# How to use old phone (LG G3) as wifi client bridge via micro usb ethernet adapter

Tags: wifi-tethering, gadgetbridge

Looking to see if I can use an android phone to "get the internet" from wifi and provide it to a ethernet cable that I intend to run way beyond my wifi range to another router I have configured as an access point. The single string data flow architecture is as thus:

[wifi device wanting WWW, e.g. iPad]<-wifi connection->["far away" wifi Access Point]<-wired connection->[micro usb ethernet adapter]<-micro usb charge port on phone->[Android phone (LG G3)]<-wifi connection->[primary wifi router]<-ethernet cable->[cable modem]<-coax->{WWW}

Does that make sense?
Is it possible?
I know I should be flashing DD-WRT to a wifi router and configuring it in client bridge mode but I don't have a spare DD-WRT compatible router lying around. I do have multiple un-used but working 2015 vintage android phones sitting unused.

Comment: [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526)